# Java one liner to create a list of String, add contents of another List<String> and return a List

Tags: java

How to create a List of String then add all the contents of another List to it and then return that list??

Consider a function:

```
public List<String> foo() {
  return Arrays.asList("some", "list", "of", "strings", "from", "foo");
}
```

A Class MyConstants:

```
public MyConstants {
  public static final String myConst = "String from Constant File";
}
```

I am writing a function `bar()` and need a *one liner* to return a list:

```
public List<String> bar() {
    return new ArrayList<String>(Collections.singleTon(MyConstants.myConst)).addAll(foo());
}
```

But `addAll()` returns boolean. Also, when I tried

```
Arrays.asList(return new ArrayList<String>(Collections.singleTon(MyConstants.myConst)).addAll(foo()));
```

It is `List<Boolean>` for pretty obvious reasons.

How can I create a list, add another list to it and then return that combined list?

Comment: Stream is way to go- your one liner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gene for the answer, I figured out apache-commons one lesser awful way other than Stream or ImmutableList builder. Here it is

```
        return ListUtils.union(Arrays.asList(MyConstants.myConst), foo());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth is there a constraint of one line?  Java collections are not great for fluent expressions. But you can abuse streams:

```
public List<String> bar() {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(MyConstants.myConst), foo().stream()).collect(toList());
}
```

A less awful way is to use Guava libraries:

```
public List<String> bar() {
    return ImmutableList.<String>builder().add(MyConstants.myConst).addAll(foo()).build();
}
```